# Define a SQL variable with Database Name

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables

With this T-SQL query I define a variable `@InDate` with some date.

```
SET 
    @InDate = (SELECT MIN(bt.CreateDate) AS [INDATE]
               FROM  
                   mydatabase.dbo.BuyTransaction bt
               LEFT JOIN 
                   mydatabase.dbo.TransactionExtraFields tef ON bt.TransDocument = tef.TransDocument 
                                                             AND bt.TransSerial = tef.TransSerial 
                                                             AND bt.TransDocNumber = tef.TransDocNumber 
                                                             AND ExtraFieldID = 1
               WHERE 
                   bt.TransDocument = 'FRM' AND tef.TextAnswer = @NumPI 
                   AND bt.TransStatus = 0)
```

But now I need to change the Database name by another variable. I try something like that to make a string in a variable which will be executed

```
SET @InDate = '(SELECT MIN(bt.CreateDate) AS [INDATE]
FROM mydatabase.dbo.BuyTransaction bt
LEFT JOIN mydatabase.dbo.TransactionExtraFields tef ON bt.TransDocument = tef.TransDocument AND bt.TransSerial = tef.TransSerial AND bt.TransDocNumber = tef.TransDocNumber AND ExtraFieldID = 1
WHERE bt.TransDocument = ''FRM'' AND tef.TextAnswer = '''+@NumPI+''' AND bt.TransStatus = 0)'

EXECUTE @InDate
```

But my problem is how can I get the execute result into a variable again. Something like `SET @InDate2 = EXECUTE @InDate` is not working...

Any idea?

Comment: Can yoy try EXEC(@InDate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sp_executesql`.  I think the syntax in your case is something like:

```
declare @InDate date;
declare @sql nvarchar(max);

set @sql = N'SELECT @InDate = MIN(bt.CreateDate)
FROM mydatabase.dbo.BuyTransaction bt
LEFT JOIN mydatabase.dbo.TransactionExtraFields tef ON bt.TransDocument = tef.TransDocument AND bt.TransSerial = tef.TransSerial AND bt.TransDocNumber = tef.TransDocNumber AND ExtraFieldID = 1
WHERE bt.TransDocument = ''FRM'' AND tef.TextAnswer = '''+@NumPI+''' AND bt.TransStatus = 0';

exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@InDate date output', @InDate = @InDate output;
```

You can also make `@NumPI` a parameter as well.

The documentation for `sp_executesql` is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001%28v=sql.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank you @Gordon. My result is null, but I think I'm almost there! I try this: `SET @SQLString = N'SELECT @InDate = MIN(bt.CreateDate)
FROM '+@myDB+'.dbo.BuyTransaction bt
LEFT JOIN '+@myDB+'.dbo.TransactionExtraFields tef ON bt.TransDocument = tef.TransDocument AND bt.TransSerial = tef.TransSerial AND bt.TransDocNumber = tef.TransDocNumber AND ExtraFieldID = 1
WHERE bt.TransDocument = ''FRM'' AND tef.TextAnswer = '''+@NumPI+''' AND bt.TransStatus = 0'`. Can you know what is wrong?

Comment: You would get `NULL` if `@NumPI` were `NULL`.  You would get an error if `NumPi` were a number.

Comment: Variables are set with values which should return a specific date. If I run the query changing variables with this values, I get that date...

Comment: @PJLG . . . Silly me.  This gets me like all the time.  The `output` keyword has to be repeated twice, once in the parameter definition and once where it gets set.  I miss this about 90% of the time when I use output parameters (and then typically remember right away).

Comment: No problem, who does not happen similar situations? Either way, you fix the issue! It's perfect now. Thank you @Gordon!

Answer (score 0):

I have done this type of issue.

Please check the sample code. Its working for me. Please change according.

```
DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(500)
    DECLARE @ParmDefinition NVARCHAR(500)
    DECLARE @IntVariable INT    
    DECLARE @Lastlname varchar(30) = 'col10 '  -- this variable use for input in sp


    SET @SQLString = N'SELECT @LastlnameOUT = '+@Lastlname+'
                       FROM TempStoreExcelData '
    SET @ParmDefinition = N'@level tinyint,
                            @LastlnameOUT varchar(30) OUTPUT'
    SET @IntVariable = 35
    EXECUTE sp_executesql
        @SQLString,
        @ParmDefinition,
        @level = @IntVariable,
        @LastlnameOUT=@Lastlname OUTPUT
    SELECT @output = @Lastlname
select @output
```